# Sort list items loaded after ajax call using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, sorting

Consider 2 files:

File 1 - list.html

```
<ul>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Ant</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
</ul>
```

File 2 - ajax.html

```
    <html>
     <body>
      <button type="button">Click</button>
      <ul id="list">
      </ul>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $("button").click(function() {
          $("#list").load("list.html ul > li");
        });
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Here file 1 contain list of items and file 2 load file 1's li tag list items to file 2's ul tag. After ajax call, how can we sort the loaded list alphabetically before it is displayed on the screen. I wanted to sort only after ajax call. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can provide a function to the callback argument of `load()` which is executed after the AJAX request completes and the new content has been added to the DOM. Try this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  let $list = $("#list").load("list.html ul > li", function() {
    $list.find('li').sort((a, b) => a.innerText < b.innerText ? -1 : 1).appendTo($list);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this inside the ajax success callback function. Also, you can user JS .sort() for sorting the names. This is a simple ajax call. You can add more properties based on your need. let's assume the result variable contains the names which you want to add:

```js
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
      url : 'Your_server_url',
      success: function(result){
        result.sort()
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            $('#list').append("<li>" + result[i] + "</li>")
        }
      },
      error: function (xhr, status) {
          console.info("cannot update list!");
      }
   });


});
```

```html
 <html>
   <body>
      <button type="button" id="myButton">Click</button>
      <ul id="list">
      </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I prefer $.ajax() since you can have better control on the data you get from the server (such as error handling or filtering the data before adding to the user view).

Comment: I disagree. First of all, the JS sort() method by default sort a string alphabetically. you need a parameter function when you are dealing with numbers. Second, Complete callback runs when the request is done. Then, you have to check the status to see it is 200 or not. Success on the other hand, runs when the response code is 200.

Comment: `result` is clearly an html document. You can't run `sort()` on that nor run a for loop on it. This whole answer is predicated on receiving a JSON array but that is not what is being requested in question